# How to save persisting data in angular route service even on refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I am basically tranferring data between 2 pages in angular using $route service and not using url params.

I get the data sent to on the second page by the first page but when I refresh the second page data is lost!

How do I solve this,I cant use url params as data will have many text fields and also will be having an array.

I am already using service to pass data but service data doesnt persist after refresh.

I dont want to make database as Its not practical I just want that data to stay on client machine.

Comment: How about localstorage?

Comment: How about services? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#

Comment: Really not enough information given about how the data is generated and passed between routes or if there is any way to retrieve from server or if it needs to be stored locally

Comment: what and how u mean localstorage? @VickyGonsalves

Comment: Basically I want to crate a multiscreen booking process and need data to be transferred through each screen

Comment: So I assume you are asking about $route.reload() rather than the browser's refresh button or location.relaod(). Am I correct?

Comment: I dont know about $route reload but when i press refresh button near url in browser service data is lost @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala - When you click on browser's refresh button, you restart your angular application. Which means everything in previously loaded document will get lost, all the javascript and angular variables. So you need to save your data to a place where there are no dependencies on the html document. For this only the browser provides you localstorage or sessionstorage. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage` to persist the data:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5SSAVHhiAZhS7Rzd8pvx)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      angular.module('app', [
        'ngStorage'
      ]).
      
      controller('Ctrl', function(
        $scope,
        $localStorage
      ){
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
          x: 42,
          y: 1
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button> + <button ng-click="$storage.y = $storage.y + 1">{{$storage.y}}</button> = {{$storage.x + $storage.y}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are always the best way to store data between controllers. A service persists data through the applications life cycle, therefore we can create a simple one like this:

**DataCacheService**

```
angular.module('dataPassingDemo').service('DataCacheService', DataCacheService);

function DataCacheService () {
  var self = this,
      _cache = {};

  self.get = get;
  self.set = set;

  function get (key) {
    if (angular.isDefined(key) && angular.isDefined(_cache[key])) {
      return _cache[key];
    }

    return false;
  }

  function set (key, value) {
    if (angular.isDefined(key)) {
      _cache[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Then, given 2 controllers:

**Controller 1**

```
angular.module('dataPassingDemo').controller('Controller1', Controller1);

function Controller1 (DataCacheService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.setName = setName;

  function setName (name) {
    DataCacheService.set('name', name);
  }
}
```

**Controller 2**

```
angular.module('dataPassingDemo').controller('Controller2', Controller2);

function Controller2 (DataCacheService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.name = DataCacheService.get('name');
}
```

You can see that we are able to pass data between the 2 controllers seamlessly.

You can get more information about services and factories from [this article](http://hashtagcoder.com/mastering-angularjs-services-part-1-factories-vs-services/).

Comment: What if page is refreshed?

Comment: If you want the data to persist when the page is refreshed, you should use localStorage. There is already a library that you can use: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage